# How to insert an overlay element and not affect page formatting

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, format

I have been working on this site (https://moodkeyboard.neocities.org/) and am trying to make it so when you add a gif image (on the bottom of the menu) it does not change the height of its container div. Essentially I want to add the element as if it had no height or width, since I just want it to be an overlay element.

Comment: Please be more specific, it's not clear what you really want to achieve. It would be nice if you add an example image in the question

Comment: If you go to the link provided and add a gif using the menu, it makes the page size adjust according to the size of the image added. I would like it to not do that and just add the image, more like how the overlays work (also on the website)